# how to stop and start threads in android which are running in background

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have two webservices and these are running in background by threads. i am checking my network connection frequently if network failed i show a dialog with "RESYNC" button.

my intention is when ever i click on RESYNC button the threads which are not completed have to start again.

i used thread.interupt() to stop thread and thread.start to start again.

this is not working fine it show the error like your thread is already running.

can any one please help me how to stop the thread and re-start it.

thanks.

Comment: There are so many questions about this topic. please do research before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `thread.stop()` to terminate threads.

You can use a volatile flag:

```
private volatile boolean running = true;

public void stop() {
  running = false;
}

public void run() {
  while(running) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A thread can't be restarted, you can stop it by `stop()`;

To start again you have to create new instance of the Thread and then call start.

Answer (score 0):

Have a while(condition) on your run() method. Inside your while loop are the things you want your thread to be doing while running. Change the value of your condition variable to false by setter method on your thread. The stop() method in java is deprecated.